# Completely disable auto import in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

The auto completion menu usually shows too many suggestions. For example, when typing "Double", there are 10 types with name "Double" popping up, from packages that I never imported.

I know I can exclude certain packages from auto import, but it doesn't solve the problem entirely. Even if I exclude package "java", it still shows types from javafx, sun, org, com, etc. How can I exclude all packages or disable auto import completely?

Answer (score 5):

You can at least disable the completion auto popup:

File (menu) -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Autopopup code completion

For me, the automatic popup gets in the way of typing and navigating anyway.

Also, I'd like to enable

Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Add unambiguous imports on the fly

Then whenever I really need it, I explicitly invoke one of the code completion variants: Ctrl-Space (Basic) or Ctrl-Shift-Space (Type Matching) or Ctrl-Alt-Space (Class name).

Comment: Sorry but I still want the auto popup. I just hate the IDE trying to be smart and adds a ton of irrelevant stuff in the popup. It seems what I wanted is impossible, at least in the community edition. Anyways, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that. Seems a little ironic, though, that you complain about IDEA being too smart, but want it to be even smarter (automatically decide which classes may be relevant). Out of curiosity: What should be the criteria for IDEA to decide if it should add a class from a specific package to the list? If you do not want any not-yet-imported-classes to trigger the import popup, then there also is the option "Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Show import popup".

Comment: Oh that's not what I meant. I want the popup list to only include the classes inside the packages imported in that file. For example, ArrayList should not be in the list unless I already imported java.util.* or java.util.ArrayList. I like IDE because they are smart but showing me 10 classes named Double is not so smart IMO.

Comment: @jetstream96 It won't pop up to ask you about `Double` if a suitable import is already in the file, unless you have two imports that both contain `Double` in them, in which case it can't tell which one. I don't think your complaint makes any sense whatsoever.